# htaccess rule drop 400 Bad Request on Backend apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lighttpd, bad-request

I have a ISPManager Lite, but i decited moving to lighttpd.
I use a **lighttpd** as a **Frontend** server and **Apache2** as **Backend**.

In normal php files i have no problem (for example, when i request **/form.php** it's return status **200**).
But when i am request any dynamic rule (for example **/login**) i get error:
**400 Bad Request**

And apache **error.log** writes:

```
[Sun Apr 07 22:25:01 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid URI in request GET core/pages/login.php/ HTTP/1.0, referer: http://sub.domain.com/core/
```

Here is config of **lighttpd.conf** domain:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "sub.domain.com" {
        proxy.server = ("" =>
                                (
                                        ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3005 )
                                )
        )
}
```

Here is **apache2.conf** host:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:3005>
        ServerName sub.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/skynet/data/www/sub.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.school.9k.su
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/skynet/data:."
        ........................................
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my **.htaccess** rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^login/?$ core/pages/login.php
```

What am I doing wrong?
How I can solve this problem?

P.S: Sorry for my English, I just learning it.

Comment: The problem is that the request doesn't start with a slash. Change `core...` into `/core...` in .htaccess- problem fixed.